# How to return chained iterators in rust

Tags: rust, iterator, ownership, borrowing

I have a simple struct that defines some kind of message to be sent over network.

```rust
struct Message {
    message_type: u32,
    user_id: u32,
    message: Vec<u8>,
}
```

And somewhere else I want to serialize it into a simple sequence of bytes. So I defined iterator for the bytes of the message like this:

```rust
impl Message {
    fn iter(&self) -> std::iter::Chain<std::iter::Chain<std::slice::Iter<'_, u8>, std::slice::Iter<'_, u8>>, std::slice::Iter<'_, u8>> {
        self.message_type
            .to_be_bytes()
            .iter()
            .chain(self.user_id.to_be_bytes().iter())
            .chain(self.message.iter())
    }

    fn data(&self) -> Vec<u8> {
        self.iter().cloned().collect()
    }
}
```

*Yes, the type keeps growing with more chained iterators, which is kind of a shame*

But I get 2 compiler errors when I try to run it

```
cannot return value referencing temporary value

returns a value referencing data owned by the current function. rustc(E0515)
```

Guess I'm not versed enough in the rust's ownership system

Comment: tips: you can write `impl Iterator<Item=u8>` as return type. (maybe not for your case but remember this as a shortcut)

Comment: Could be a solution: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=57c72d9b15777cd0c6e57e592b933430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem why rust borrow checker is complaining is because `to_be_bytes()` functions return an array which is stored on stack. The code is attempting to create a iterator to a object that is allocated on stack and this iterator is outliving the object.

```
self.message_type.to_be_bytes()
```

For example:
This creates an array on stack and `.iter()` is only valid as long as this object exists.

There are couple of ways fix this. Make the iter and eventual conversion to bytes all in the same function.

```
fn data(&self) -> Vec<u8> {
    self.message_type
        .to_be_bytes()
        .iter()
        .chain(self.user_id.to_be_bytes().iter())
        .chain(self.message.iter()).map(|x| *x).collect()
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=129af6e7da3d1e3a9454fffbb124e170

> Caution: Whenever you convert to bytes, confirm whether you want little endian/big endian and all the bytes follow the same endianess.

Comment: "The problem why rust borrow checker is complaining is because to_be_bytes() functions return an array which is stored on stack." that haft false, stack or not that not why rust is complaining. You should not think to the stack in a language like rust. The answer is more because no one own the array so it would be invalid to have a reference to it.